# REST Service Connection Use list from top site in a subsite

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-rest-api, sub-site

I have a top site containing many lists about suppliers and related datas.
I created a subsite to give access to some of those datas to other factories from our group. My plan is to get the supplier list from the top site through a REST Service and then link it to a new list stored on the subsite to display suppliers of both factories.
My problem is that the REST service doesn't work. 
I used this link : https://my.site.net/personal/XXXXXX/TopSite/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/LISTNAME
This link works in internet explorer, I see all my list items.
I create the REST Service but when I do on a page inser-->data view--> REST-ListName     I have a current data source error "the server returned a non specifid error when trying to get the data from the data source. check the format and content of your query and try again"

What am I doing wrong?
Is it really possible to do what I want? Meaning when I edit items in the linked data view originally contained in the topsite list, will it also update them?
Or do I need to try something completely new?

Thank you for your help, I'm a newby sharepoint intern...

Answer (score 2):

So, the reason because of which the REST API is not working : You are trying to fetch data from cross domain where your "**Personal Site**" and the site where you are fetching data both are different.

there is a work around for the problem. Instead of REST, you can write Search Queries. For reference, visit the following link:
https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview

Comment: thanks for the answer. However I don't understand the problem... My subsite is under the top site : https://my.site.net/personal/XXXXXX/TopSite/SubSite/SitePages/Home.aspx.  I will read the link you gave me!